# DIR - Ordering the list. Show subfiles right after the parent folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If I use the DIR command (dir /s /b > file.txt) I noticed it orders like this >

```
C:\TEST\&TEMP&
C:\TEST\FILE1
C:\TEST\FILE2
C:\TEST\&TEMP&\SUBFILE1
```

If I wanted the DIR command to display in this order >

```
C:\TEST\&TEMP&
C:\TEST\&TEMP&\SUBFILE1
C:\TEST\FILE1
C:\TEST\FILE2
```

How would you do that? I need my list sorted in this order to be used with my backup utility.

Comment: Try `dir /s /b /ON > file.txt` For more info `dir /?`

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS? The command line in Windows has absolutely nothing to do with "DOS".

Comment: I tried > dir /s /b /ON > file.txt and that gave the same results.

Comment: I'm using DOS on a windows 2008 server.

Comment: The Windows command prompt isn't DOS. MS-DOS is an old obsolete 16-bit operating system. Unless you're running MS-DOS under a VM, you're not using DOS on Windows Server 2008. The distinction is an important one and could make a big difference in the answer. MS-DOS only has a small fraction of the features offered by the Windows command line.

Comment: Ross - Thanks for the clarity. It's just command line (through telnet) on the server. You're correct in that it's not MS-DOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
dir /s /b >test_temp.txt
type test_temp.txt |sort >test.txt
del /q file_temp.txt
pause
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Just wondering why you need that "type" command to do the sort?

Comment: `dir /s /b | sort > test.txt`